# New 'Hello World' app fails with classNotFound for MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

I have found several posts regarding classNotFound for MainActivity but all seem to be related to differences in libraries between the main app and support libraries, stuff like that.  I have a situation where I am simply creating a new application in Android Studio and with zero modifications, running the helo world default app, fails with this error.

```
07-20 23:25:46.012 7152-7152/com.rythmair.lvlvalidation D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-20 23:25:46.012 7152-7152/com.rythmair.lvlvalidation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rythmair.lvlvalidation, PID: 7152
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.rythmair.lvlvalidation/com.rythmair.lvlvalidation.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.rythmair.lvlvalidation.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rythmair.lvlvalidation-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2968)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.rythmair.lvlvalidation.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rythmair.lvlvalidation-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2958)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rythmair.lvlvalidation.MainActivity
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
07-20 23:26:13.377 7152-7152/com.rythmair.lvlvalidation I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7152 SIG: 9
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Are you sure the class "MainActivity" is there, in the right package, with the right File- and Classname?

Comment: give a snapshot of your project viewer and main activity

Comment: Try to clean your project and build

Comment: show your manifest file

Comment: show your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your manifest if it is not there

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was an odd one, given the error.  The issue turned out to be access rights on the device I was testing (I think).  I caught in one part of the stack that it couldn't write code to data/data/... Upon digging in a bit further, I found that I was signed in on my tablet as a test user that I use to validate licensing functionality.  While logged in as this user, it would fail any time I tried to build the app with the error shown above.  Once I signed back in on my tablet as myself, this issue no longer occurs.